# KML polygon only showing up in preview

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I have a KML file and made a fusion table out of this. 
In this fusion table there are a lot of polygons split one per row.
One of these rows contains following polygon:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>4.479382,50.95028 4.479507,50.950126
 4.479653,50.949947 4.479828,50.949733 4.479941,50.949767 4.480345,50.94989 
4.481543,50.948703 4.481571,50.948675 4.481519,50.94866 4.480786,50.948436 
4.480783,50.948441 4.480592,50.948373 4.480443,50.948309 4.480426,50.948301 
4.48037,50.948277 4.480279,50.948216 4.4801,50.948037 4.479825,50.948314 
4.479676,50.94827 4.479665,50.948267 4.479372,50.948181 4.479354,50.948172 
4.479263,50.948147 4.478968,50.948063 4.478968,50.948063 4.479273,50.947683 
4.479597,50.947277 4.479316,50.947176 4.479985,50.946633 4.48004,50.946588 
4.480702,50.946051 4.481081,50.945742 4.480946,50.945554 4.48053,50.945347 
4.480373,50.945268 4.48022,50.94523 4.4797,50.945143 4.479497,50.945419 
4.479086,50.945992 4.478416,50.945788 4.478309,50.94586 4.477876,50.946167 
4.477888,50.946216 4.478038,50.946882 4.478071,50.946879 4.478114,50.947004 
4.477663,50.947448 4.47719,50.947878 4.477133,50.94789 4.476584,50.948023 
4.47635,50.948079 4.476282,50.948029 4.476294,50.948017 4.47655,50.947759 
4.476747,50.947527 4.476918,50.947186 4.476921,50.94718 4.476921,50.94718 
4.476904,50.947161 4.476581,50.947041 4.476363,50.946908 4.476222,50.946787 
4.476051,50.946585 4.475605,50.945866 4.47549,50.945572 4.475423,50.945457 
4.475364,50.94539 4.474899,50.944991 4.474282,50.944517 4.474209,50.944402 
4.474138,50.944215 4.474213,50.944401 4.474226,50.944417 4.474245,50.944438 
4.474257,50.944452 4.474373,50.944541 4.474784,50.944855 4.474974,50.94501 
4.475605,50.944623 4.475823,50.94449 4.476053,50.944349 4.475823,50.94449 
4.475605,50.944623 4.474974,50.94501 4.474994,50.945026 4.475337,50.945314 
4.475401,50.945383 4.475425,50.945421 4.475484,50.945511 4.475508,50.945559 
4.475722,50.945376 4.475722,50.945376 4.476277,50.944903 4.476722,50.944523 
4.476722,50.944523 4.478126,50.944855 4.478927,50.945014 4.479182,50.944685 
4.479257,50.944588 4.479497,50.944332 4.479054,50.943961 4.478219,50.943253 
4.478219,50.943253 4.477985,50.942901 4.477974,50.942881 4.476116,50.943658 
4.475724,50.943821 4.475724,50.943821 4.476116,50.943657 4.477974,50.942881 
4.477965,50.942865 4.477951,50.942845 4.477827,50.94266 4.477601,50.942643 
4.477213,50.942614 4.476788,50.942583 4.476351,50.94255 4.47554,50.942489 
4.475353,50.942474 4.475177,50.942461 4.474992,50.942447 4.47476,50.942429 
4.474371,50.942399 4.473767,50.942352 4.473618,50.94234 4.473541,50.942009 
4.473515,50.941979 4.473484,50.941955 4.473466,50.941944 4.473466,50.941944 
4.473266,50.941818 4.47304,50.941629 4.473026,50.94161 4.472923,50.941475 
4.472819,50.941292 4.472751,50.941181 4.472589,50.940971 4.472509,50.940868 
4.472509,50.940868 4.472432,50.940768 4.472339,50.940675 4.472162,50.940527 
4.472162,50.940527 4.471742,50.940174 4.472401,50.93963 4.472366,50.939611 
4.473093,50.93902 4.473464,50.938718 4.472916,50.938515 4.472513,50.938378 
4.471592,50.938098 4.471244,50.937995 4.470833,50.937884 4.470064,50.938326 
4.4695,50.938656 4.468968,50.938251 4.468085,50.937605 4.46806,50.937586 
4.467965,50.937601 4.469422,50.939346 4.469097,50.939508 4.468961,50.939621 
4.468698,50.939849 4.468132,50.940302 4.468183,50.940313 4.467443,50.940799 
4.467906,50.941071 4.4668,50.941797 4.465734,50.942506 4.465885,50.942631 
4.466098,50.942808 4.466295,50.942996 4.466558,50.943223 4.466796,50.943527 
4.466924,50.943699 4.468189,50.943182 4.467658,50.942774 4.468189,50.943182 
4.468567,50.943476 4.468929,50.943357 4.469033,50.943423 4.469124,50.94348 
4.46917,50.943509 4.46958,50.943768 4.46959,50.943779 4.469809,50.943791 
4.469926,50.943794 4.470095,50.943798 4.470091,50.943989 4.470367,50.944 
4.470357,50.944179 4.470688,50.944282 4.470686,50.944356 4.471413,50.944393 
4.471411,50.944426 4.471406,50.94448 4.471395,50.944563 4.471372,50.94472 
4.471368,50.94479 4.471362,50.944879 4.470595,50.944846 4.470573,50.945072 
4.471246,50.945107 4.471243,50.945132 4.471236,50.945187 4.471232,50.945217 
4.471213,50.945361 4.471204,50.945436 4.471201,50.9455 4.470753,50.945483 
4.470745,50.945539 4.470412,50.945523 4.470402,50.945614 4.470683,50.945626 
4.470564,50.945961 4.471569,50.946406 4.473756,50.947496 4.474915,50.948073 
4.475741,50.948419 4.47603,50.948576 4.476021,50.948603 4.475952,50.948722 
4.475933,50.948755 4.475864,50.948863 4.475823,50.948991 4.475832,50.949016 
4.475875,50.949131 4.475942,50.949248 4.475977,50.949288 4.476035,50.949352 
4.476104,50.94943 4.476261,50.94961 4.476317,50.949747 4.476319,50.949765 
4.478017,50.950223 4.478046,50.950188 4.478062,50.950177 4.478046,50.950188 
4.478017,50.950223 4.477909,50.950351 4.477927,50.950353 4.47804,50.950367 
4.478507,50.950432 4.478629,50.950483 4.478683,50.950515 4.479041,50.950728 
4.479133,50.950609 4.479267,50.950437 4.479389,50.950282 
4.479382,50.95028</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs><innerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing><coordinates>4.476928,50.949872 4.477174,50.949495 4.47841,50.949804 
4.478728,50.94943 4.47841,50.949804 4.477174,50.949495 4.476928,50.949872</coordinates>
</LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs><innerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
<coordinates>4.476873,50.948207 4.477043,50.948046 4.477209,50.947887 
4.477043,50.948046 4.476873,50.948207</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs>
<innerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>4.470775,50.939605 4.470675,50.939524 
4.470738,50.93956 4.470975,50.939657 4.47112,50.939715 4.47118,50.939738 
4.471275,50.939784 4.471383,50.939849 4.471471,50.93992 4.471337,50.939852 
4.470992,50.939709 4.470775,50.939605</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs>
<innerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>4.469713,50.938817 4.469691,50.938801 
4.469771,50.938851 4.469915,50.938942 4.46997,50.938977 4.470004,50.939003 
4.469713,50.938817</coordinates></LinearRing></innerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

The problem with this polygon is that is it not showing up on the map?
But when I preview only this polygon it is :/

Does anyone experienced something similar or know a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have some inner polygons that look like lines to me.  Removing those might help as well as simplifying the outer boundary.  [KML with winding direction calculations](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_FusionTablesPolygonNotShowing.kml)

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2961159?hl=en) might help.

Comment: Remove the `<innerBoundaryIs>` tags and it [displays for me](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1hnZkcTvHNHR_wd1Nrzgf_UTV_07VOwKOJU7mS4rY)

Comment: indeed removing the inner polygons solves the problem, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some inner polygons that look like lines to me. Removing those might help as well as simplifying the outer boundary. [KML with winding direction calculations](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_FusionTablesPolygonNotShowing.kml)

Remove the `<innerBoundaryIs>` tags and it [displays for me](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1hnZkcTvHNHR_wd1Nrzgf_UTV_07VOwKOJU7mS4rY)

Comment: Those innerboundarys define a whole in the polygon, so when these are deleted the original shape is changed.. You know another way without deleting those?

Comment: At least 2 of them don't define a hole, they are just lines.  If there are some that are important, put those back and try reversing the winding direction if you still have issues.